Encounter error when i run the code and Unable to convert my project into apk form
I was trying to run this project mentioned below on my pc and then convert it into apk form but i get this error whenever i run flutter build command.
The error also comes when i run the code.
project link-https://github.com/Pratikdate/ecard
/C:/Users/HP/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/device_preview-1.1.0/lib/src/views/tool_panel/sections/section.dart:39:40: Error: The getter 'subtitle2' isn't defined for the class 'TextTheme'.

'TextTheme' is from 'package:flutter/src/material/text_theme.dart' ('/D:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/text_theme.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'subtitle2'.
style: theme.textTheme.subtitle2?.copyWith(
^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/HP/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/device_preview-1.1.0/lib/src/views/tool_panel/sections/settings.dart:56:34: Error: The getter 'backgroundColor' isn't defined for the class 'ThemeData'.
'ThemeData' is from 'package:flutter/src/material/theme_data.dart' ('/D:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/theme_data.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'backgroundColor'.
color: toolbar.backgroundColor,
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/HP/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/device_preview-1.1.0/lib/src/views/tool_panel/sections/settings.dart:87:34: Error: The getter 'backgroundColor' isn't defined for the class 'ThemeData'.
'ThemeData' is from 'package:flutter/src/material/theme_data.dart' ('/D:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/theme_data.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'backgroundColor'.
color: toolbar.backgroundColor,
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/HP/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/persistent_bottom_nav_bar-5.0.2/lib/neumorphic_package_by_serge_software/neumorphic_card.dart:57:57: Error: The getter 'backgroundColor' isn't defined for the class 'ThemeData'.
'ThemeData' is from 'package:flutter/src/material/theme_data.dart' ('/D:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/theme_data.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'backgroundColor'.
final color = decoration.color ?? Theme.of(context).backgroundColor;
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/HP/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/device_preview-1.1.0/lib/src/views/theme.dart:31:11: Error: No named parameter with the name 'toggleableActiveColor'.
toggleableActiveColor: accentColor,
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/HP/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/device_preview-1.1.0/lib/src/views/theme.dart:54:11: Error: No named parameter with the name 'toggleableActiveColor'.
toggleableActiveColor: accentColor,
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/HP/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/device_preview-1.1.0/lib/src/views/tool_panel/tool_panel.dart:83:34: Error: The getter 'headline6' isn't defined for the class 'TextTheme'.
'TextTheme' is from 'package:flutter/src/material/text_theme.dart' ('/D:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/text_theme.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'headline6'.
style: theme.textTheme.headline6?.copyWith(
^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/HP/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/device_preview-1.1.0/lib/src/views/tool_panel/sections/subsections/device_model.dart:175:32: Error: The getter 'subtitle2' isn't defined for the class 'TextTheme'.
'TextTheme' is from 'package:flutter/src/material/text_theme.dart' ('/D:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/text_theme.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'subtitle2'.
style: theme.textTheme.subtitle2?.copyWith(
^^^^^^^^^
Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
I tried different things such as
The getter 'accentColor' isn't defined for the class 'ThemeData'
but none of them works!!
Please help

The error causing package is device_preview and the issue is related to theme.

Can you suggest how to remove this error?? @Ultranmus

Do you want to use this package? If you really don't need it, just comment the relevant code and it will work else I can try cloning your repo tomorrow to solve your prblm.From my experience I believe there is something in package that is conflicting with your current code related to some name.

same issue i am facing due to persistent_bottom_nav_bar probably this package needs to get updated.
Request and PR is already created for the same.
https://github.com/BilalShahid13/PersistentBottomNavBar/pull/363/commits/8e631ae584ce974bf694e9fba40c1524af2922b2

From the error, you seem to be using device_preview 1.1.0.
According to the change log of device preview, support for flutter 3.22.x family landed in device preview 1.2.0.
Update your device preview version and try again.
device_preview: ^1.2.0

